# Generic type as a parameter of an abstract method?

Tags: java, generics

I'll try to ask this question as generic (no pun intended) as possible.

Let's say I have an object "garage" that works as a container for cars. It looks something like this:

```
public abstract class Garage {
    public abstract List<? extends Car> getCars();
    public abstract void addCarToGarage(Car car);
}
```

Because I am very rich, I will have different type of garages, some only contains my sport cars, another only my SUVs and so on.

So one of my garages will look like this:

```
public class SportCarGarage extends Garage {
    @Override
    public List<SportCar> getCars() {
        // code to return the cards
    }

    @Override
    public void addCarToGarage(Car car){
        // code to add car to garage
    }
}
```

Now you may already see my problem. I can implement `getCars()` so that it will return a list of `SportCar`. But I would need to check every single car for its type if I call `addCarToGarage` and I won't get an syntax error if someone tries to add a SUV in my SportCarGarage.

I would want something like this:

```
public abstract class Garage {
    public abstract List<? extends Car> getCars();
    public abstract void addCarToGarage(? extends Car car);
}
```

But that will just give me a syntax error. I guess there is an easy solution for that and I just don't know what to search for. Hope you can help.

Comment: Accidentally posted this as an answer earlier - looks like others have answered the question, but anyway: Is there some fundamental difference in what 'adding a car to the garage' does, based on what particular type of car it is? If not, then I would suggest that you simply implement the 'addCarToGarage' method within the abstract class itself.

Comment: +1 for @TomFromThePool. That's one of the benefits of generic code: no need for subclasses just to get type safety. If the garage management code can be generic, no need to duplicate it. You only need that if the subclass has some extra methods or needs to do something special according to car type. So you could maybe use `Garage<SportsCar>` instead of `SportsCarGarage`.

Comment: @TomFromThePool - I have to think about that. Actually TypeSafety is my main concern at the moment. But Thilo mentioned that I could get TypeSafety the other way, too. I'll have to try, of course the project I am actually working on is a bit more complexe. But thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the `Garage` generic and re-use the type in the `addCarToGarage` method:

```
public abstract class Garage<T extends Car> {
    public abstract List<T> getCars();
    public abstract void addCarToGarage(T car);
}
```

Then, the `SportCarGarage` would look like this:

```
public class SportCarGarage extends Garage<SportCar> {
    @Override
    public List<SportCar> getCars() {
        // code to return the cards
    }

    @Override
    public void addCarToGarage(SportCar car){
        // code to add car to garage
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Unless the SportsCarGarage does something very special, it seems that the two methods don't need to be abstract now (and can be implement in Garage).

Answer (score 0):

You need to parameterize the whole class.

```
public abstract class Garage<T extends Car>  {
    public abstract List<T> getCars();
    public abstract void addCarToGarage(T car);
}
```

This will also make sure you're using coherent types between all the methods.

Edit: typo

Comment: Have you compiled that? :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you basically just want the following?

```
public abstract class Garage<T extends Car> {
    public abstract List<T> getCars();
    public abstract void addCarToGarage(T car);
}
```

And

```
public class SportCarGarage extends Garage<SportCar> {
    @Override
    public List<SportCar> getCars() {
        // code to return the cards
    }

    @Override
    public void addCarToGarage(SportCar car){
        // code to add car to garage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to make the Garage generic:

```
public abstract class Garage<T extends Car> {
   public abstract List<T> getCars();
   public abstract void addCarToGarage(T car);
}
```

Then you can do

```
Garage<SportsCar> sportsGarage = ....
```

I have left the class abstract, but maybe you don't need to make subclasses anymore just to adjust it for the different types of cars.

It seems you can at least implement these two methods in a generic way now.

If you really want the specialized subclasses you can do

```
class SportsGarage extends Garage<SportsCar> {
      ....
}

Garage<SportsCar> sportsGarage = new SportsGarage();
```