# How to achieve type safety with generics?

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I am currently trying to extend a bigger project. Some things in the project are given and I am having a few problems to make my extension type safe.

I'll make the example code more general.

```
public abstract class Garage {

    public <T extends Car> void parkCars(T... car){
        // add cars to a list
    }
}
```

The abstract class `Garage` is given and there are several given classes that extend from the `Garage`. Like `SportCarGarage` or `SUVCarGarage`. Those garages behave differently in some ways. But of course every garage has the `parkCars` function. `Car` also has some different children like `SportsCar`, `SUVCar`, etc. Those are given, too.

Now I want that I only can park `SportCars` in a `SportCarGarage`.

My hope was that it would work something like this:

```
public class SportsCarGarage<T extends SportsCar> extends Garage {

}
```

...

```
    SportsCarGarage<SportsCar> sportsCarGarage = new SportsCarGarage();
    // Would be great if I could do this without adding <SportsCar>

    SUVCar bmwX5 = new SUVCar();
    SportsCar porsche911 = new SportsCar();

    sportsCarGarage.parkCars(porsche911); // works!
    sportsCarGarage.parkCars(bmwX5); // shouldn't work, but does. :(
```

I guess I just have the syntax wrong somewhere. But there should be a way to stop other devs to park cars in the wrong type of garage without having to overwrite the `parkCars` function in every single type of garage!?

edit:

I guess my example is just wrong and that's the reason it won't work with the code I am actually working on. Thanks for the help...

Comment: Why did you not follow the advice given by @kocko on [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26507271/1225328)? Because this is actually the design you need...

Comment: You say you are extending a bigger project. Does this mean you cannot modify the Garage class?

Comment: @sp00m: If I understood it correctly, kockos example still had an abstract "parkCars". I thought there should be a way without overwriting it in every single sub class.

Comment: @DavidtenHove: It depends on how much would change and if I would have to touch every single class that extends from Garage.

Comment: Changing the Garage interface to have a generic type (like in the answers below), would require all subclasses of Garage to be modified (or give compiler warnings of raw types). If this is not a problem, the answers below are fine.

Comment: @Feroc An abstract class does not have to provide only abstract methods. Kocko probably thought that each garage would have its own logic, but you are allowed to put common logics into the abstract class: http://pastie.org/9680273.

Comment: @sp00m: That's exactly my problem. Only if I overwrite it with the specific type it works. I've tried all the solutions below and it won't work. Maybe my example isn't accurate enough.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
public abstract class Garage<T extends Car> {

    public void parkCars(T... car) {
        // add cars to a list
    }
}

public class SportsCarGarage extends Garage<SportsCar> {
}
```

> sportsCarGarage.parkCars(bmwX5); // shouldn't work, but does. :(

After refactoring, it gives a compiler error!

Comment: That's my current way of doing it. My hope was that there is a way without having to overwrite parkCars in every single class that extends from Garage.

Comment: You don't have to override the parkCars method in the SportsCarGarage for this to work though.

Comment: You don't have to. It's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

your type in class and your type in method `parkCars` are different,
to make it work you need to change your interface to

```
public abstract class Garage<T extends Car> {

    public  void parkCars(T... car){
        // add cars to a list
    }
}
```

now your `SportsCarGarage` will accept only sports cars

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about the generic `parkCars` implementation, then here it is:

```
public abstract class Garage<T extends Car> {

    public List<T> parkedCars = new ArrayList<>();

    public void parkCars(T... cars) {
        Collections.addAll(parkedCars, cars);
    }
}

public class SportsCarGarage extends Garage<SportsCar> {}
```